# Avoid getting "Null" on Paper form Barcode LiveCycle Java Script

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

I will start by telling you that I'm not a programer. I designed a form in Adobe LiveCycle, but now I want include the value of certain fields into a Paper Form Barcode with a specific separators. My problem is that I do not want to get "null" when a field is left empty. I need the field to just stay empty and the string of values to just continue o the next field. This what I get when I scan the barcode after leaving 2 fields empty.
**"1 field|2 field^3 field|4 field|*null*|
*null*|last field|**

But this whay need to get:
**"1 field|2 field^3 field|4 field|||last field|
Empy line for other purposes"**
Any help will be greatly appreciated. I have been searching for an answer but  I have not been able to ajust the answers that I have found to what I need.
**This is the code that I'm using:**

```
// This function ensures that the barcode will update 
// when a change is made to any field on the form.
function depends(node) 
{ 
for (var i = 0; i < node.nodes.length; ++i) 
{ 
var child = node.nodes.item(i); 
if (child.isContainer) 
depends(child); 
} 
} 

// Return a field surrounded by quotes and followed with a separator 
function fmtField(fieldName, separator) 
{ 
  var str = fieldName.rawValue+ separator; 
  return str; 
} 



// Force all fields in the form to be updated in the dataset 
depends(xfa.form);  
// Generate the CSV string that will be encoded in the barcode 

var bar = "|"; 
var eso= "^"
var newLine = "\n"; 
var s = fmtField(accountNum, bar);
s += fmtField(formerFirstName, eso); 
s += fmtField(formerMiddleInitial, bar); 
s += fmtField(formerLastName, bar); 
s += fmtField(newFirstName, bar) 
s += newLine
s += fmtField(newMiddleInitial, bar); 
s += fmtField(newLastName,bar);
s += newLine
s += "Empty line for other purposes"

// Assign the string to the barcode for encoding

this.rawValue = s ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function fmtField(fieldName, separator) 
{ 
  var str = {};
  if(fieldName.rawValue == null){
    str = "";
  }
  else{
    str = fieldName.rawValue+ separator;
  } 
    return str; 
}
```

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if it solved your problem.